# Is it safe to use styluses with iPads?

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation, stylus

I know my question sounds stupid but I can't imagine scratching my iPad mini screen!

I have iPad mini (Retina Display) and I'm considering getting [Applydea Maglus](http://www.amazon.de/Maglus-Stylus-Eingabestift-austauschbarer-Spitze/dp/B00GMIVHQU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1396199669&sr=8-1&keywords=Applydea%20Maglus) stylus.

But is it safe to use styluses with iPads? Do they scratch the screens?

*Feel free to suggest any stylus!*

Comment: Yes, it's completely safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20€ is a bit steep for a stylus, you can find many on e-bay and such for way less than 5€. They're all generally the same thing: a stick with a rubber dome on one end. The rubber has a similar capacitance to human skin, so it can be sensed by the screen. The rubber dome on the end is squishy and very soft, it will not scratch your screen.

Answer (score 1):

It is completly safe.
In its normal state, the rubber top of the stylus is soft and smooth, so it won't scratch your screen.
Even when applying a lot of force there will be virtually no risk.

There would need to be something sharp (e.g.piece of broken glass) between the screen and the stylus to do some damage and even then it would require quite some pressure to be applied before the screen takes any damage.